# Shell script force stop without waiting for the exit code

Tags: linux, bash, shell, script, exec

I have written a shell script `checklick.sh` on my CentOS box with the following content:

```
#!/bin/sh

#
# description: check link through rtmpdump
#

. /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions

DUMPUTIL=/usr/bin/rtmpdump
"$DUMPUTIL" -B 1 -r "$1" -o /tmp/rtmp-checker.log && echo_success || echo_failure
```

and executed by

```
./checklink.sh rtmp://tv2.globisoft.net/live/tv2
```

Now, from the following output:

[image]

I need to know how to force exit the script when the log prints `ERROR: RTMP_ReadPacket, failed to read RTMP packet header` because I'm calling the script from PHP `exec` native function and is waiting forever for the exit code but the script does not return the exit code.

Comment: Did you write `exit 1` or the exit code that you want in the `function echo_failure`?

Answer (score 0):

How about testing each line of the command output?

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r line; do
  echo "$line"

  if [[ "$line" == "TEST" ]]; then
      exit
  fi
done < <(cat testfile)
```

The above reads the output from a given command (in this case "cat testfile"), then echos the result. It checks for a line that equals "TEST" and exits if it finds a match.